# Twig - Get URL for canonical tag

Tags: symfony, twig, canonical-link

I'm looking to create a dynamic rel="canonical" tag in my application which pulls in the current URL but want to ensure any query parameters are removed. E.g http://www.example.com/test/?page=2 should have the canonical as http://www.example.com/test/, therefore `{{ app.request.uri }}` doesn't work as this pulls in `?page=2` as well.

Does anyone know how to pull in the absolute path of a page without the query parameters?

Comment: I don't think it's possible (maybe I'm wrong), but you could write Twig extension that splits `app.request.uri` by `?` char...

Comment: I've just remembered that there is `app.request.baseUrl`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This will work,

```
{{ url(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) }}
```

Comment: +1 Haven't tried it but this seems to be really neat solution :)

Comment: Aren't query strings provided in the route params?

Comment: @SteveBuzonas, nope it's only generate url base on current route name and it's params. If u have additional query strings u need to add it by yourself

Comment: In your 404 page if you extend the template this code is used in, make sure to put this inside an if block or 404 page will become a 500 page because route doesn't exist.

Comment: it's ugly as sin, but it still gets the job done in Symfony 4.4. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I just tried to dump `baseUrl` and can confirm that it does not work.

However, this **works**:

```
{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost ~ app.request.baseUrl ~ app.request.pathInfo }}
```

I know, it's not pretty but it does the job :)

Comment: This is what i am looking for, above solution not including parameters to generated url.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, cause the other one will result in 500 errors for every single error page like 403, 404, and so on!